# Are there any activation functions which on inputting integer data will produce the output as integers?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, activation-function

Idea is to create the model for ethereum mining which deals with only integer data.

Answer (score 1):

There [are quite a lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function) of activation functions $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that their restriction to integers $f|_\mathbb{Z} : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ produce integer values. $f(x) = max\{0,x\}$ is quite famous.